# multiple firing on element fires jquery multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've three icons on my page. Each icon clicked, ajax called and contented fetched and appended to another div respectively. The problem I face now, if an icon fired multiple time continuously, it fires ajax for the no of time it's clicked.

Noticing this problem, I check, if the request pass in property called `sweep`. If it does I would empty the div and append the content; this is to avoid duplicate data being appended. But now when the icons pressed multiple times, it appends more than once the same data.I can't find what causing this to happen. For some reason, I had to use `append` and not `html` to put in the content.
I thought can overcome this by `event.stopPropagation` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation` but they're of no use. Please check my code below and help me to fix it...thanks..

screen cast of the problem:
[demo](http://screen.stackideas.com/screencast_2016-09-02_17-50-54.mp4)

code:

```
//links in the footer clicked
    $('body').off('click.footer').on('click.footer', '[data-footer] ul li a', function(event){
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
        var layout = $(this).data('ck-tab');

        $(this).trigger('ck.chat.layout', [{'layout':layout}]);

        if(layout == 'list'){
        ckit.render({"layout":'getConversations', "sweep": 1, "limit":localStorage.getItem("cListlimit"), "userId": localStorage.getItem("ckuser")});
      }else if(layout == 'contact'){
        ckit.render({"layout":'getContacts', "sweep": 1, "limit":localStorage.getItem("cntlimit"), "userId": localStorage.getItem("ckuser")});
      }else if(layout == 'setting'){
        //ckit.render({"layout":'getSettings', "sweep": 1});
        ckit.setting();
      }

    });
```

I check if data already appended to the div this way. But even this shows the data multiple times..

```
if($.inArray(data[i].id, temp)<0) {
            //add to array
            temp.push(data[i].id);
        }
```

function to display content:

```
function display(value, arg){

var wrapper = $('[data-body-content]');
if(arg[0]['sweep'] == 1){
  temp = [];
  wrapper.empty();

}

setTimeout(function(){
         for(var i=0; i < counter;i++){

        if($.inArray(data[i].id, temp)<0) {
            //add to array
            temp.push(data[i].id);
        }
      }//end for
        console.debug(temp);
        wrapper.append(temp);

        }, 300);

}
```

Comment: You could add a boolean variable to keep track of which data is currently loaded. Then every time the button is clicked, you could check if the data u want is already loaded and not send the ajax request.

Comment: @divinemaniac, the content will a list of users. So I track user id, if already exist in array. Even this way, multiple firing causes the id to show up more than once..

Comment: are you sure that the ajax request is not returning different ids?

Comment: yes, returning the same id